# Access a view inside Fragment which is initialised by using getFragmentbyTag()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The app is crashing using `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HELLO");`. I want to refer the textview inside `HelloFragment` after getting the fragment from the back stack.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    HelloFragment helloFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_load);


        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new HelloFragment(), "HELLO");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new HiFragment(), "Hi");
               fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("HELLO");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        helloFragment = (HelloFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HELLO");
        helloFragment.textView.setText("aufa");

    }
}
```

**HelloFragment.java**

```
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Inflating the layout for this fragment **/
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
        textView = v.findViewById(R.id.idhai);
        textView.setText("Hello");
        return v;
    }
}
```

In short I want to access a fragments textview when I get it from the stack using FindFragmentbyTag()

***Log***

```
Process: com.example.test, PID: 23551
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.example.test.HelloFragment.textView' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.example.test.HelloFragment.textView' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
```

Comment: could you add you crash stackTrace?

Comment: I have added the log

Comment: TextView it´s null. You are calling it before fragment view it's created. You should handle that text view from within the fragment itself

Comment: I know. I wanted a way to handle the textview from outside the fragment. Is there a way that the view can be created so that textview is not null?

Comment: Well since we clarified that that is a big nono, if you wanted to do it any way the best way is to communicate to the activity once the fragment inflated the view. There are severals ways of doing that.. Interfaces, View models etc. I would still suggest not to do it.

Comment: Here the view is not created right? Can I still access the textview without getting a null exception when i retrieve the fragment from the stack?

Comment: You will get a NPE every-time you try to access the textview before the fragment inflated the view

Comment: Okay. One last thing is there way to achieve the following implementation? As in can the view also be saved or can I forcefully create the view?